# How to reply an embed discord.py command extension

Tags: python, discord.py

I cannot reply an embed message (code below)

```
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Error message:

```
In message_reference: Unknown message
```

Purge command if needed

```
@bot.command(name='Purge', help= 'Deletes a certain amount of messages')
async def purge(ctx, limit: int, *, Reason=None):

  embed = discord.Embed(title="Purged", description=f"{limit} messages was purged.", colour=discord.Colour.green())
  embed.add_field(name="Reason", value=Reason, inline=False)
  await ctx.channel.purge(limit=limit)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

So my question is how to reply an embed? It seemed like you can't send an embed using ctx.reply() method

Comment: Well, what is the problem here? I don't understand where the connection between code and your question is. Is the `embed` not sending? Are you encountering any errors with the code?

Comment: Please provide more information. We don't really get what is not working.

Comment: Yeah the embed is not sending

Answer (score 0):

## Don't delete the message

The problem is that you are deleting the message and then trying to reply to it, which can't happen, therefore the Unknown message error since the message is already deleted and does not exist anymore

### What to do

I suggest not replying here at all since I think everyone will just delete that message after using the purge command. But if for some reason you want to reply, I don’t think there is a efficient way of doing that in a purge command. You can just not reply and just send the embed in a normal message and that would work fine